# Latex preview not working in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, latex

I'm following instructions on this page: https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html. I have managed to install `dvipng` and successfully replicated the given example page as a `.png` file. Then, when I try to run `org-latex-preview` by `C-c C-x C-l` in Emacs, I get the following message:

`Creating LaTeX previews in section... done.`

However there no rendering happening anywhere. I'm running Emacs 26.3. on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

The value of `org-preview-latex-default-process` is `dvipng` and the value of `org-preview-latex-process-alist` is as follows:

```
Value:
((dvipng :programs
          ("latex" "dvipng")
          :description "dvi > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvipng." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
          (1.0 . 1.0)
          :latex-compiler
          ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
          :image-converter
          ("dvipng -D %D -T tight -o %O %f"))
 (dvisvgm :programs
           ("latex" "dvisvgm")
           :description "dvi > svg" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "svg" :image-size-adjust
           (1.7 . 1.5)
           :latex-compiler
           ("latex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
           :image-converter
           ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S -o %O"))
 (imagemagick :programs
               ("latex" "convert")
               :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and imagemagick." :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
               (1.0 . 1.0)
               :latex-compiler
               ("pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
               :image-converter
               ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))
```

The document I'm trying to render is the example given in the above link:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC latex :tangle latex/example.tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
e^{i\pi} = -1
\]

\[
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
\]

\end{document}

#+END_SRC
```

If I press `C-u C-u C-c C-x C-l`, I receive the same message `Creating LaTeX previews in section... done.` as above and once again no rendering.

Comment: What is the value of `org-preview-latex-default-process`? If it is not `dvipng`, then try setting to that. Edit your question and add the value. Also add the value of `org-preview-latex-process-alist` for good measure.

Comment: Can you show us the document you are trying to create previews in? What happens if you try `C-u C-u C-c C-x C-l`?

Comment: @Tyler, Done. Added the example and response to the key-combo.

Comment: Incidentally, I would recommend working from the built-in org documentation (i.e., `M-x org-info`). Worg gets updated very irregularly (if at all), and the tutorial you were referring to appears to be six or seven years old! It can be confusing, as org changes a lot between versions.

Comment: That example is a LaTeX file to be used for testing the dvipng installation: it is *NOT* an org file to be used for testing LaTeX preview. The example you should follow is under "Basic Usage" : put that in your Org mode file and then do `C-c C-x C-l` on each of them.

Comment: @NickD, thanks. I now receive the following error: `org-compile-file: File "/tmp/orgtexKoxDu3.dvi" wasn’t produced.  Please adjust ‘dvipng’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the example you are working from has mislead you. You can include LaTeX snippets in your org files directly, you don't need to wrap them in a src block. In fact, src blocks are ignored when org tries to preview the LaTeX snippets.

Try this:

```
* Org heading

This is an ordinary org file. The following LaTeX code can be previewed:

\[
e^{i\pi} = -1
\]

\[
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
\]

Latex code inside src blocks doesn't get previewed:

#+BEGIN_SRC latex :tangle latex/example.tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
e^{i\pi} = -1
\]

\[
\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
\]

\end{document}

#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for pointing this out. Now I receive the following error when invoking `C-c C-x C-l`:


`Creating LaTeX preview...
org-compile-file: File "/tmp/orgtexX7Vwnu.dvi" wasn’t produced.  Please adjust ‘dvipng’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.`

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. This example works for me on Ubuntu 18.04, with the same dvipng settings as you have listed in your question ??

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved! I had to install the `texlive-latex-extra` package as I was missing some `.sty` files.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you ever preview latex src blocks? Its nice to jave latex as src blocks as we can then edit them in latex mode.